# JQuery function submit() not submitting form

Tags: jquery, validation, submit

I can't get the form to submit, the `alert ($('#submit').val());` in the `else` with the submit comes up so the code is getting into the right place, but the form is not submitting.

Form has an id of othernames, submit button was called name and id of save at one point, currently both are set to submit.

any help appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// force content into cnamex
$('#submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent submit
    error = '';
    for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        if  ($('#cname' + i).length > 0) {
            if ($('#cname' + i).val().length == 0) {
                error = 'Names for those attending are required';
            }
        }
    }
    if (error != '') {
        alert (error);
    }
    else {
        $('#othernames').submit();  
        alert ($('#submit').val());
    }
});
});
```

HTML is PHP generated, this is a version of it without any boxes to validate

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="othernames" id="othernames"  method="post"    action="" target="_self">
<div class="table">
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
        <td colspan="3" ><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm  Order" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

This is with fields to validate:-

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="othernames" id="othernames"  method="post" action="" target="_self">
<div class="table">
<table width="100%" border="0"><caption>Enter names for tickets, (if any)</caption>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Email (Optional)</th>
    <th scope="col">Club</th>
  </tr><tr><td><input name="cID[]" type="hidden" value="11"><input name="cname[]" id      ="cname0" type="text" size="15" maxlength="20"></td>
            <td><input name="cemail[]" id="cemail0" type="text" size="15"     maxlength="60"></td><td><input name="cclub[]" type="text" size="15" maxlength="25"    value="VRA - United Kingdom"></td></tr><tr><td><input name="cID[]" type="hidden"    value="11"><input name="cname[]" id="cname1" type="text" size="15" maxlength="20"></td>
        <td><input name="cemail[]" id="cemail1" type="text" size="15" maxlength="60"></td><td><input name="cclub[]" type="text" size="15" maxlength="25"  value="VRA - United Kingdom"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" ><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm  Order" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

Problem Solved using  reyaner's suggestion, thank you. JQuery now reads, and html uses a submit button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// force content into cnamex
    $('#submit').click(function(event){
            error = '';
        for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            if  ($('#cname' + i).length > 0) {
                if ($('#cname' + i).val().length == 0) {
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent submit
                error = 'Names for those attending are required';
                }
            }
        }
        if (error != '') {
            alert (error);
        }
    });
});



enter code here
```

Comment: Can you show your html

Comment: You should try: `$(this).closest('form').get(0).submit();` BTW, IDs must be unique on context page

Comment: Instead of having a submit button and then using `event.preventDefault();` to stop the default functionality, why not simply use a regular button and add this functionality?

Comment: you should post your html..., also you could let the submit-button as it is, and prevent the form submit like so: `$("form").submit(function(e){ //do stuff, prevent submit or dont if its ok..  });`

Comment: HTML added to question, I have tried both the above suggestions neither is working for me at the moment,

Comment: Working code above is over complicated, I will remove the if error != and add the alert to the text removing the error variable completely. Once again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Justinas Jurciukonis may well work, however this is the final code I am going with as it is shorter. Checks between 0 and 10 possible fields if PHP has created them, alerts and prevents submission if they are blank, for my purposes that is sufficient validation but of course you could add more to the inner if, and also be more creative than an alert box.

```
    $('#submit').click(function(event){
    for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        if  ($('#cname' + i).length > 0) {
            if ($('#cname' + i).val().length == 0) {
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent submit
                alert('Names for those attending are required');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

html generated by PHP loop as required

```
    <tr>
    <td><input name="cname[]" id="cname0" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="cname[]" id="cname1" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm  Order" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<form action='#' method='post' onSubmit='return validate()'>...</form>
```

Then $('#submit').click change to function validate(){...}, remove .preventDefault(), and finnaly on success return true, else return false.

```
function validate(){
    error = '';
    for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      if  ($('#cname' + i).length > 0) {
          if ($('#cname' + i).val().length == 0) {
              error = 'Names for those attending are required';
          }
      }
  }
  if (error != '') {
    alert (error);
    return false;
  }
  else {
    //$('#othernames').submit();  
    alert ($('#submit').val());
    return true;
  }
});
```